# Why doesn't std::rotl() compile on my Clang 13.1.6 installation?

Tags: c++, clang, identifier

I've installed brew on my new laptop and when attempting to compile my code with Clang 13.1.6 I get an identifier error using `std::rotl()`. What could be the reason for this? I believe it works fine on my Windows computer.

This is my code:

```
#include <bit>

int main()
{
    std::rotl(100, 1);
}
```

This is the error message I get:

```
antonadamson@AirsomthorAnton ~ % g++ test.cpp -o -std=c++20 test 
test.cpp:7:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rotl'
rotl(100, 1);
^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: How is it not working?  Can we get a [mre] and the error you are getting?

Comment: `std::rotl` is C++20, are you compiling with `-std=c++20` switch? Did you include `<bit>` header? We can't say much without [mcve].

Comment: This is also likely Apple Clang, which does its own versioning and is decently far behind actual clang, which is at version 14 now.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I do try to compile with -std=c++20, but it doesn't work unfortunately. Also, I did include <bit>.

Comment: You asked about `std::rotl()` and posted an error about `rotr` - different function, using unqualified name lookup, with no code to guess whether there's a `using` declaration anywhere. Please make some effort to ask an answerable question.

Comment: @sweenish I did g++ --version and it is Apple clang version 13.1.6. Does it follow the C++20 standard?

Comment: @Useless I apologize, misspell. std::rotl is however dual to the std::rotr function, so it's kind of potayto potahto.

Comment: Apple clang supports this library feature since `11.0.3` (Xcode `11.4`), so it should work. Please provide code which triggers this error.

Comment: `rotr` only supports unsigned types.  `97` is an `int` which is signed.

Comment: Here is MCVE with regular clang: https://godbolt.org/z/Y1Ton6f8K

Comment: Ok problem is that you are using signed value and this function is only for unsigned types!